# VBA RemoveDuplicates: Cannot set Columns by variable

Tags: vba, duplicates

I worked with RemoveDuplicates and cannot find any other way than to hard code the columns settings. This is code would work:

```
Worksheets("SheetName").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").RemoveDuplicates _
Columns:=VBA.Array(1, 2, 3), _
    Header:=xlYes
```

But this code would throw "runtime error 5":

```
Dim ArrayColumns() As Variant
ArrayColumns = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3)

Worksheets("SheetName").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").RemoveDuplicates _
Columns:=ArrayColumns, _
    Header:=xlYes
```

As I actually would like to use an array with 100+ entries that might even change over time, I am not so happy with the first solution.

Can you help me?

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `(` before and `)` after your `ArrayColumns`

```
Sub RemDuplicates()

Dim ArrayColumns() As Variant
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
ArrayColumns = Array(1, 2, 3)

With Sht
    .Range("A:Z").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(ArrayColumns), Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works now. I thought I have tried this solution but that time it must have been a Long-array or any other problem.

PS: is With Sht .Range.... End With faster than my Sht.Range....? Or why did you use this?

Comment: @PeterFrey maybe it's my style of coding, but i prefer using `With` statements, in case in the future you want to run more coding on this worksheet, then it's easier to set reference.

Comment: Why exactly does this work, @Shai Rado ?  Do the brackets force evaluation, or something?

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up with the original posting where it was stated ArrayColumns = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3). One would only use VBA.Array with RemoveDuplicates if one had Option Base 1 set for the module. That is why ArrayColumns = Array(1, 2, 3) worked finally [assuming Option Base was default 0]